# Use @EnableResourceServer with custom Authorization Provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to find what classes I need to implement in order to use the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation and interact with our custom OAuth2 server and token storage.

The goal is to package it as a library and share it across other services. So basically I need to implement:

1. Custom Token endpoint.
2. Custom Refresh endpoint.
3. Custom token validation filter *(to avoid the call to `/check_token`)* since we are using JWT, we are ok with just making sure the token is properly signed.
4. Save the token *(on the resource service)* in Redis.
5. The custom endpoint to retrieve the user information.

So far I've seen the following classes:

1. [TokenEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html)
2. [RefreshTokenGranter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/refresh/RefreshTokenGranter.html)
3. [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.html)

But since I haven't been able to find much documentation, I'm wondering whether I'm a bit lost or these classes are not intended to be overridden and it will be better to create my custom logic and not rely on the `@EnableResourceServer`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe where you might want to start looking is `ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. This follows a similar programming model to `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and will give you some context for what can be configured.

From there, take a look at `ResourceServerTokenServices` and `TokenStore` for points 1, 3, 4, and 5.

Now, regarding #2, since you'd also like to have applications refresh tokens, it sounds like you might want to create two libraries, one for services that want to authorize requests using OAuth2 (`@EnableResourceServer`) and one for services that want to address those resource servers (`@EnableOAuthClient`). In that case, also take a look at `OAuth2RestTemplate` and `ClientTokenServices`.

Also, take a look at http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html if you haven't already as this is where I pulled most of the above from.

There are some examples at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2 that you might find helpful on the Resource Server side, specifically https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java

And there is an example of a client at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/client/src/main/java/client/ClientApplication.java

Hope that helps!